# What are the left cosets of $ D_{8} $ with respect to the subgroup $H=\langle a^2\rangle$?

Tags: group-theory, dihedral-groups

Let $D_8$ denote the dihedral group of order $16$, aka the group of symmetries of the regular $8$-gon.

Using Lagrange's theorem there are $16/4$ cosets which I have worked out to be $H$, $aH$, $bH$, $abH$. However, in the solutions for this question it is stated that the only cosets are $H$, $aH$ and $bH$. I am not sure how this makes sense as this is contradicting Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: is 4 the number of total cosets so the number of left cosets can be anything less than or equal to 4 ?

Comment: Indeed, this must be an error in the stated solution as there can never be $3$ cosets for a group of order $16$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft does 4 include all the cosets or just the left cosets with respect to H ?

Comment: What even is $D_8$?

Comment: @iheartmaths If $H$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$, then there are $|G|/|H|$ left cosets of $H$ and $|G|/|H|$ right cosets of $H$. You are correct that the solution violates Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Presumably $D_8$ is the dihedral group of an octagon, and $a$ is a rotation of order $8$, and $b$ is one of the reflections. You should edit your question to clarify this. (Some authors use $D_8$ to refer to the dihedral group of a square.)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft It's probably worth mentioning that in general, a left coset of $H$ need not be a right coset, unless $H$ is a normal subgroup. (Of course $H$ itself is always a left coset and a right coset.) In this case $H$ is indeed normal, since it is a characteristic subgroup of $\langle a \rangle$, which is normal in $G$ (it has index 2).

Comment: @Bungo what does a 'characteristic subgroup of <a>' mean?

Comment: @iheartmaths It means that $H$ is invariant under automorphisms of $\langle a \rangle$, meaning that if $\phi$ is any automorphism of $\langle a \rangle$ then $\phi(H) = H$. Any subgroup of a finite cyclic group is characteristic, because there is exactly one subgroup of each possible order, and automorphisms preserve order. There's a useful theorem that if $H$ is characteristic in $N$ and $N$ is normal in $G$, then $H$ is normal in $G$. Don't worry if you haven't encountered these notions yet; it's just a preview of what you will probably be learning soon :-)

Answer (score 0):

By Lagrange, the order of the left (or right) coset space $D_8/\langle a^2\rangle$ is $|D_8|\big/|\langle a^2\rangle| = 16/4$. Your solutions manual is in error or the question is asking for something else.